# Same seed across different gpus in multiple workers in huggingface/pytorch

Tags: pytorch, multiprocessing, huggingface-transformers, multi-gpu

This is more of a discussion question because I have a workaround to suit my use case.

My understanding was if I am training my model on multiple GPUs (say n GPUs) in a `DistributedDataParallel` fashion, all GPUs will receive different batches, and the effective batch size would be `n x batch_size_per_gpu.` With this understanding, I created a simple script to see how I can control the randomness of the batches, as shown below. But to my surprise, different workers with the same `id` received the same `seed` and the same `shard`. This would mean, in effect, all the GPUs would be seeing the same data at the same time, thus this would not increase the batch size.

*This behavior IMO defeats the purpose of doing parallel training because it does not increase the batch size. Please correct me if I there are any gaps in my understanding or if this is not how we are supposed to use DDP.*

The print statement in the `SeedTest.seedTest` function prints the `seed` received by different workers across GPU (Refer to the output -- I reordered it to highlight the point.).

**Output:**

```
rank=0 worker=0 seed=6909045637428952499 shards=[0]
rank=1 worker=0 seed=6909045637428952499 shards=[0]

rank=0 worker=1 seed=6909045637428952500 shards=[1]
rank=1 worker=1 seed=6909045637428952500 shards=[1]

rank=0 worker=2 seed=6909045637428952501 shards=[2]
rank=1 worker=2 seed=6909045637428952501 shards=[2]

rank=0 worker=3 seed=6909045637428952502 shards=[3]
rank=1 worker=3 seed=6909045637428952502 shards=[3]
```

**Code**

```py
import typing as tp
import os
import torch
from datasets import IterableDataset  # huggingface - transformers datasets
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForMaskedLM, DataCollatorForLanguageModeling, TrainingArguments, Trainer


class SeedTest:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    def seedTest(self, shards: tp.List[tp.Any]) -> tp.Any:
        rank = int(os.environ.get("LOCAL_RANK", 0))
        worker_info: tp.Any = torch.utils.data.get_worker_info()

        print(f"rank={rank} worker={worker_info.id} seed={worker_info.seed} shards={shards}")

        yield {
            "seq": "ATGCATGC"
        }


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    model_name ="InstaDeepAI/nucleotide-transformer-v2-50m-multi-species"
    model = AutoModelForMaskedLM.from_pretrained(model_name, trust_remote_code=True)
    tokeniser = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name, trust_remote_code=True)
    collator = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(tokenizer=tokeniser, mlm=False)

    _d_shard = IterableDataset.from_generator(SeedTest().seedTest, gen_kwargs={"shards": list(range(4))})
    _d_shard = _d_shard.map(lambda x: tokeniser(x['seq']))
    _d_shard = _d_shard.select_columns(["input_ids", "attention_mask"])
    _d_shard = _d_shard.with_format("torch")

    trargs = TrainingArguments(output_dir="test", max_steps=1, dataloader_num_workers=4)
    trainer = Trainer(
        model,
        args=trargs,
        train_dataset=_d_shard,
        data_collator=collator
    )
    trainer.train()
```

**Run command**

```bash
torchrun --nproc_per_node 2 seed_test.py
```